# Run Batchable class from .Net code

Tags: batch, .net

I have created a batch apex class and am able to run this from within the developer console using execute anonymous. I want to be able to trigger this batch to run from within a .net program. Is there any way to achieve this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, you can use the Tooling API to perform execute anonymous calls in the same way you would from the developer console.

See:

- Apexcode API: [executeanonymous()](http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/apexcode/Content/sforce_api_calls_executeanonymous.htm).
- [Tooling API REST API](http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/api_tooling/Content/intro_rest_overview.htm?SearchType=Stem&Highlight=executeAnonymous%7Cexecuteanonymous):  `/executeAnonymous/?anonymousBody= <url encoded body>`
- [Tooling API SOAP API](http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/api_tooling/Content/intro_soap_overview.htm): `executeanonymous(string apexcode)`

Answer (score 3):

In addition to [Daniel's answer](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/a/66649/119), depending on your own preferences you could also create a custom Apex [SOAP webservice](https://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/apexcode/Content/apex_web_services_methods.htm) or [REST endpoint](https://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/apexcode/Content/apex_rest.htm) at which you launch your batch. Either of those is also easily accessibly from .NET.